# How to create a Java archive (.jar) file using NetBeans IDE 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am trying to create a Java archive (.jar) file using NetBeans IDE 8.2. 
[image: pic1]

After I select **Clean and Build**, the three jar files in the lib folder get **deleted** 
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]
...and I get the following errors:

error: package org.jsoup does not exist import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

error: package org.jsoup.nodes does not exist import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

error: package org.jsoup.nodes does not exist import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your lib folder should not be in the dist folder - netbeans compiler always deletes and recreates the dist and build folders when creating jar files.
Get the jar files and the directory lib out of the dist and put it maybe in the main directory of your program (or any other directory in your computer but /dist and /build) and then in your IDE right click your project, choose Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder and add your jsoup files.

Hope this helps!